# Clickhouse client syntax error kafka integration

Tags: apache-kafka, syntax, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

ClickHouse client version 18.16.1 and I'm following this blog post-https://altinity.com/blog/2020/5/21/clickhouse-kafka-engine-tutorial

when creating a table I'm using this syntex

```
CREATE TABLE readings (
    readings_id Int32 Codec(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    time DateTime Codec(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
    date ALIAS toDate(time),
    temperature Decimal(5,2) Codec(T64, LZ4)
) Engine = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(time)
ORDER BY (readings_id, time);
```

and I'm getting an error that says

"""
Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 76 (line 2, col 23): Codec(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
time DateTime Codec(DoubleDelta, LZ4),
date ALIAS toDate(time),
temperature Decimal(5,2) Codec(T64, LZ4)
)
ENGINE = MergeTr. Expected one of: token, ClosingRoundBracket, Comma, DEFAULT, MATERIALIZED, ALIAS, COMMENT, e.what() = DB::Exception
"""

let me know what I'm doing wrong thanks.

Comment: ClickHouse client version 18.16.1 does not support this syntax (Codec), because Codecs did not exist that time.

Comment: thanks for your help.. how can I update clickhouse client? on ubuntu 20.0.4

Comment: clickhouse client usually came with a server. What server version do you use? `select version()` ?

Comment: yes thanks now it's working